# What is "- O" meaning when declare a DTD element type?

Tags: xml, dtd, sgml

According W3C [XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-elementdecl) specification, element is declared in form of :

```
[45]    elementdecl    ::=      '<!ELEMENT' S Name S contentspec S? '>'
[46]    contentspec    ::=      'EMPTY' | 'ANY' | Mixed | children
```

And samples on [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_elements.asp) is :

```
 <!ELEMENT br EMPTY>
```

But in [html 4.01 strict dtd](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd) element br is ：

```
<!ELEMENT BR - O EMPTY                 -- forced line break -->
```

Why the second declaration add **“- O”**? What it means? And Where can I find the offical document about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hyphen means required, the O means optional. So "- O" means that the opening tag is required, and the closing tag is optional. You can read more in [§3.3.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.3)

Answer (score 3):

Like @erickson said, the hyphen means "required" and "O" means optional. The first -/O is for the start tag and the second -/O is for the end tag. This is called tag minimization.

***Tag minimization is only allowed in SGML DTDs.*** This is why you see it in the HTML Strict DTD, but you don't see it in the XML Spec or the XML examples on w3schools.